# Next.js Vanilla JS script won't run on deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js to build a simple static site. The only vanilla JS script I have is for a mobile menu - to toggle it open and add a class to the body to prevent scrolling:

```
if (process.browser) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    let mainNav = document.querySelector('#menu')
    let navBarToggle = document.querySelector('#toggle')
    let noScroll = document.querySelector('body')

    navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function () { 
      mainNav.classList.toggle('active')
      navBarToggle.classList.toggle('close')
      noScroll.classList.toggle('lock-scroll')
    })
  })
}
```

The if `process.browser` statement is something I had to add to get it to work on localhost, which works but only on the first load, e.g. when I first run next dev. After I navigate to another page it won't load, I guess because the page isn't being fully re-rendered, which the script needs or something?

Then when I deploy the site the toggle isn't working at all, even on first load.

Anyway, any help in getting this working would be much much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`process.browser` has been deprecated, use `type of window`

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    let mainNav = document.querySelector('#menu')
    let navBarToggle = document.querySelector('#toggle')
    let noScroll = document.querySelector('body')

    navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function () { 
      mainNav.classList.toggle('active')
      navBarToggle.classList.toggle('close')
      noScroll.classList.toggle('lock-scroll')
    })
  })
}
```

if that solution doesn"t work, you can use [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)